# LDAP query for Window AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jitsi

For authentication in Jitsi Meet, we would like to read out a Windows AD group with an ldap query. Unfortunately our ldap query does not work.

```
LDAP_URL=ldaps://server.domain.local:636/
LDAP_BASE=DC=domain,DC=local
LDAP_BINDDN=CN=bind_user,OU=Administrative Accounts,OU=Benutzer,DC=domain,DC=local
LDAP_BINDPW=*

LDAP_FILTER= (&(|objectclass=user))(|(memberof=CN=group,OU=Jitsi,OU=Sicherheit,OU=Gruppen,DC=domain,DC=local)
(primaryGroupID=4989))
```

The error must be due to the filter, it works with the filter `LDAP_FILTER = (sAMAccountName =% u)`.

Can you tell me what is wrong with our query.

Comment: Are the users members of the group _directly_, or through nested group memberships?

Answer (score 0):

A few things stand out to me:

1. The `|` in front of `objectClass` should not be there.
2. You have two closing parentheses after the `objectClass` condition, but the second one should be moved to the end of the whole query.
3. Oddly, `objectClass=user` will actually end up including other objects than just user accounts (like computer accounts). If you want to filter to only user objects, you have to use both `(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)`. But that would only matter if you have other types of objects as members of that group.
4. Maybe this is just an error with pasting into the question, but there is a line break before `(primaryGroupID=`
5. I've never used Jitsi, but it may or may not like the space after `LDAP_FILTER=`. The other examples I see online don't show a space there.

It should look like this:

```
LDAP_FILTER=(&(objectclass=user)(objectCategory=person)(|(memberof=CN=group,OU=Jitsi,OU=Sicherheit,OU=Gruppen,DC=domain,DC=local)(primaryGroupID=4989)))
```

That means: find all user objects that are either members of that group, or have a primary group ID of `4989`.